Unicode-bidi: plaintext not working in firefox
I'm writing a library that takes user submitted text and renders it in the browser, among other things.
The user may submit text that mixes lines of RTL and LTR text, and each line should be rendered in the appropriate alignment and direction.
To this end, I'm presenting text in paragraph html elements with unicode-bidi: plaintext which is intended for this behavior.
I am seeing a strange behavior where a line wrap in a single span of RTL text causes the second line to be rendered LTR. This only occurs in Firefox. I'm hoping to find a workaround or fix. Toggling the unicode-bidi attribute on the paragraph element fixes the issue, as does opening the developer console for me. Seems very erratic.
I am submitting text like this:
זוהי פסקה של טקסט. הנה קישור ראשון, זהו טקסט מילוי. הנה קישור שני, זהו טקסט מילוי. והנה קישור שלישי, זהו טקסט מילוי.

Which is wrapping, and the wrapped portion is aligned left instead of right.
This is a demo link: https://blush-madlen-53.tiiny.site/#/United_States/New_York/Style_examples#Links_in_right-to-left_text
Image:

(Currently the demo is testing unicode-bidi: normal on the section and paragraph, and unicode-bidi: plaintext on child elements of paragraph as per discussion with Andj, but if section is unicode-bidi normal or unset, and the paragraph itself is unicode-bidi plaintext, the same issue exists.)

Any particular reason you set the dir to auto  and applied unicode-bidi: plaintext to the same element? Since your example would display correctly without using unicode-bidi.

@Andj I may be wrong but it seemed to me dir=auto gives me the entire div RTL or LTR, but it doesn't specify that I want each text line of the DIV to be evaluated for RTL/LTR status separately, that was my experience

I'm not sure what you mean by lines. You have two lines of text in your example made up of multiple inline elements, with one element wrapping across the two lines. My understanding is that plaintext would create an isolation for each inline element and apply paragraph heuristics to each inline element. All this existing within an LTR block level container as a parent. Not surprised Firefox is confused. Its a complex layout for unadorned UBA. The question is at which stage is the bug occurring in Firefox. May be related to when the text wraps, I'll need to experiment.

Sorry, by line I mean series of inline elements of the div that begin with a break tag or block element that knocks them onto their own line, my understanding is that plaintext should let each one be aligned separately

@Andj I uploaded a new demo with alternating lines of RTL/LTR as you suggested, and with your suggested styling, minus my JS workaround, and I see the problem persisting.
It could be that this styling isn't the right way to express what I want, but what I want is pretty straight forward, as is implemented in Gmail / most text editors, that RTL and LTR are judged per line-break-separated-line (not wrapping line) of content. Thanks for your help

I'm posting a workaround but am still hoping someone might be able to figure out why this is happening.
My solution was to take the parent element of the text container, set that to unicode-bidi: unset, then put unicode-bidi: plaintext on the text container itself. So it seems Firefox might have different defaults - Chrome seems to default to unicode-bidi: normal whereas Firefox seems to default to unicode-bidi: isolate, and perhaps having a plaintext element within an isolate container causes the behavior in Firefox, but not in Chrome even when I use Firefox's default styles.
So it seems like a difference in CSS defaults combined with a subtle bug in how Firefox handles elements nested within others of different unicode-bidi values, but manual unsets should solve the problem.
Edit: This workaround doesn't work consistently.

Edit: This workaround does work
  // Fixes firefox unicode bug
  paragraphElement.style.unicodeBidi = 'unset';
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    paragraphElement.style.unicodeBidi = 'plaintext';
  });


using your test page, I seem to get best results in firefox if the unicode-bidi property to set to normal on section and paragraph, and apply plaintext to span. Alternatively setting everything to normal and replying on dir=auto

Although a test that includes a mix of RTL and LTR spans would be a better test.
